# Python: find out whether a list of integers is coherent

Tags: python, sequence, python-itertools

I am trying to find out whether a list of integers is coherent or 'at one stretch', meaning that the difference between two neighboring elements must be exactly one and that the numbers must be increasing monotonically. I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3149493/145400) a neat approach where we can group by the number in the list minus the position of the element in the list -- this difference changes when the numbers are not coherent. Obviously, there should be exactly one group when the sequence does not contain gaps or repetitions.

Test:

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> l2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
>>> l3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
>>> l4 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4]
>>> l5 = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> def is_coherent(seq):
...     return len(list(g for _, g in itertools.groupby(enumerate(seq), lambda (i,e): i-e))) == 1
... 
>>> is_coherent(l1)
True
>>> is_coherent(l2)
False
>>> is_coherent(l3)
False
>>> is_coherent(l4)
False
>>> is_coherent(l5)
False
```

It works well, but I personally find that this solution is a bit too convoluted in view of the simplicity of the problem. Can you come up with a clearer way to achieve the same without significantly increasing the code length?

## Edit: summary of answers

From the answers given below, the solution

```
def is_coherent(seq):
    return seq == range(seq[0], seq[-1]+1)
```

clearly wins. For small lists (10^3 elements), it is on the order of 10 times faster than the `groupby` approach and (on my machine) still four times faster than the next best approach (using `izip_longest`). It has the worst scaling behavior, but even for a large list with 10^8 elements it is still two times faster than the next best approach, which again is the `izip_longest`-based solution.

Relevant timing information obtained with `timeit`:

```
Testing is_coherent_groupby...
   small/large/larger/verylarge duration: 8.27 s, 20.23 s, 20.22 s, 20.76 s
   largest/smallest = 2.51
Testing is_coherent_npdiff...
   small/large/larger/verylarge duration: 7.05 s, 15.81 s, 16.16 s, 15.94 s
   largest/smallest = 2.26
Testing is_coherent_zip...
   small/large/larger/verylarge duration: 5.74 s, 20.54 s, 21.69 s, 24.62 s
   largest/smallest = 4.28
Testing is_coherent_izip_longest...
   small/large/larger/verylarge duration: 4.20 s, 10.81 s, 10.76 s, 10.81 s
   largest/smallest = 2.58
Testing is_coherent_all_xrange...
   small/large/larger/verylarge duration: 6.52 s, 17.06 s, 17.44 s, 17.30 s
   largest/smallest = 2.65
Testing is_coherent_range...
   small/large/larger/verylarge duration: 0.96 s, 4.14 s, 4.48 s, 4.48 s
   largest/smallest = 4.66
```

Testing code:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import timeit


setup = """
import numpy as np
def is_coherent_groupby(seq):
    return len(list(g for _, g in itertools.groupby(enumerate(seq), lambda (i,e): i-e))) == 1

def is_coherent_npdiff(x):
    return all(np.diff(x) == 1)

def is_coherent_zip(seq):
    return all(x==y+1 for x, y in zip(seq[1:], seq))

def is_coherent_izip_longest(l):
    return all(a==b for a, b in itertools.izip_longest(l, xrange(l[0], l[-1]+1)))

def is_coherent_all_xrange(l):
    return all(l[i] + 1 == l[i+1] for i in xrange(len(l)-1))

def is_coherent_range(seq):
    return seq == range(seq[0], seq[-1]+1)


small_list = range(10**3)
large_list = range(10**6)
larger_list = range(10**7)
very_large_list = range(10**8)
"""


fs = [
    'is_coherent_groupby',
    'is_coherent_npdiff',
    'is_coherent_zip',
    'is_coherent_izip_longest',
    'is_coherent_all_xrange',
    'is_coherent_range'
    ]


for n in fs:
    print "Testing %s..." % n
    t1 = timeit.timeit(
        '%s(small_list)' % n, 
        setup,
        number=40000
        )      
    t2 = timeit.timeit(
        '%s(large_list)' % n, 
        setup,
        number=100
        )     
    t3 = timeit.timeit(
        '%s(larger_list)' % n, 
        setup,
        number=10
        )
    t4 =  timeit.timeit(
        '%s(very_large_list)' % n, 
        setup,
        number=1
        )
    print "   small/large/larger/verylarge duration: %.2f s, %.2f s, %.2f s, %.2f s" % (t1, t2, t3, t4)
    print "   largest/smallest = %.2f" % (t4/t1)
```

Test machine:

- Linux 3.2.0 (Ubuntu 12.04)
- Python 2.7.3 (gcc 4.1.2)
- numpy 1.6.2 built with Intel compiler
- CPU: E5-2650 @ 2.00GHz
- 24 GB of memory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how bout

```
sorted_list = sorted(my_list)
return sorted_list == range(sorted_list[0],sorted_list[-1]+1)
```

or if its only coherent if it is already sorted

```
return my_list == range(my_list[0],my_list[-1]+1)
```

if you are using python 3 you will need `list(range(...))`

Comment: Couldn't you then just do `list == range(list[0], list[-1]+1)`? :)

Comment: You don't need to sort or any `min` or `max`. Monotonicity is requirement! See: `>>> l1 == range(l1[0], l1[-1]+1) ->
True` -- I like this approach, now we just need to think about performance :)

Comment: yeah I dont know ... it depends on how you define coherent ahh you added more examples in an edit I see :) ...

Comment: You'll need to wrap `range()` in `list()` for Python 3; maybe worth mentioning that.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: I defined it as "meaning that the difference between two neighboring elements must be exactly one and that the numbers must be increasing monotonically" in the question.

Comment: Would you mind discussing the performance of this approach? It requires creation of one potentially large list and comparing two potentially large lists. Also, regarding the requirements, you can safely add `list == range(list[0], list[-1]+1)` to your answer! (edit: now Carl has already done it...)

Comment: range(0,100000000) takes about .5 seconds ... comparison took about 1 second (on my system)

Comment: The `list == range(list[0], list[-1]+1)` solution wins, see edit in my answer for detailed timing info. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm overlooking something in your examples, this simpler solution is actually shorter.

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> l2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
>>> l3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
>>> l4 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4]
>>> l5 = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> 
>>> def is_coherent(seq):
...     return seq == range(seq[0], seq[0]+len(seq), 1)
... 
>>> is_coherent(l1)
True
>>> is_coherent(l2)
False
>>> is_coherent(l3)
False
>>> is_coherent(l4)
False
>>> is_coherent(l5)
False
>>>
```

The results of some basic performance tests seem to indicate that this method is significantly quicker (I've added your example as `is_coherent2`):

```
Carl > python -m timeit -s 'from t import is_coherent, l1' 'is_coherent(l1)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.782 usec per loop
Carl > python -m timeit -s 'from t import is_coherent, l3' 'is_coherent(l3)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.796 usec per loop
Carl > python -m timeit -s 'from t import is_coherent2, l1' 'is_coherent2(l1)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.54 usec per loop
Carl > python -m timeit -s 'from t import is_coherent2, l3' 'is_coherent2(l3)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.93 usec per loop
```

Comment: Basically the same as suggested by @JoranBeasley -- how would you expect this to perform compared to the itertools-based solution? Would you like to perform some benchmarking?

Comment: Updated with some `timeit` examples.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a numpy solution:

```
import numpy as np

def is_coherent(x):
    return all(np.diff(x) == 1)

is_coherent(np.array([1,2,3,4,5]))
Out[39]: True

is_coherent(np.array([1,2,3,4,8]))
Out[40]: False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_coherent(seq):
    return all(x==y+1 for x, y in zip(seq[1:], seq))
```

Comment: Remove the brackets and you turn your list comprehension into a generator comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

This short circuits and does not create an extra list making it useful for testing very large lists.

```
def is_coherent(l):
    return all(a==b for a, b in izip_longest(l, xrange(l[0], l[-1]+1)))
```

Or

```
def is_coherent(l):
    return all(l[i] + 1 == l[i+1] for i in xrange(len(l)-1))
```

Comment: this will probably be faster and more memory efficient than my solutuions

Comment: I take it back this is much slower than my method ... but probably better memory useage so still should work well for very large lists ( like greater than 10million)

Comment: @JoranBeasley:  More memory efficient?  Yes.  But faster?  Probably not because list creation is ridiculously fast even for relatively large lists.

Comment: @JoranBeasley:  Also, comparing two lists as equal is implemented in C.

Comment: The `izip_longest`-based one scales best, interesting solution (see edit in my answer)!

Answer (score 0):

i dont know python but i know its functional so heres a small loop function that will do it if you change the syntax for correct python.

**PSEUDO CODE**

```
def is_coherent(seq):
     for x in xrange(1, len(seq)-1):
        if (seq[x+1]-seq[x] != 1)  return false;   
     return true
```