# Is a column in pandas.DF() monotonically increasing?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I can check if the index of a pandas.DataFrame() is monotonically increasing by using is_monotonic method. However, I would like to check if one of the column value is strictly increasing in value(float/integer) ?

```
In [13]: my_df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,5,7,6,9])

In [14]: my_df
Out[14]: 
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  5
4  7
5  6
6  9

In [15]: my_df.index.is_monotonic
Out[15]: True
```

Comment: Please, precisely specify what you mean with "strictly increasing". What is the expected output in your example case?

Answer (score 39):

**Pandas 0.19** added a public [`Series.is_monotonic`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.is_monotonic.html) API (previously, this was available only in the undocumented `algos` module).

**(Updated)** Note that despite its name, `Series.is_monotonic` only indicates whether a series is monotonically *increasing* (equivalent to using `Series.is_monotonic_increasing`). For the other way around, use `Series.is_monotonic_decreasing`.
Anyway, both are non-strict, but you can combine them with [`is_unqiue`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.is_unique.html) to get strictness.

e.g.:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,2,3], columns = ['A'])

my_df['A'].is_monotonic    # non-strict
Out[1]: True

my_df['A'].is_monotonic_increasing    # equivalent to is_monotonic
Out[2]: True

(my_df['A'].is_monotonic_increasing and my_df['A'].is_unique)    # strict  
Out[3]: False

my_df['A'].is_monotonic_decreasing    # Other direction (also non-strict)
Out[4]: False
```

You can use `apply` to run this at a DataFrame level:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[1,1,1],'C':[3,2,1]})
my_df
Out[32]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  1  3
1  2  1  2
2  3  1  1

my_df.apply(lambda x: x.is_monotonic)
Out[33]: 
A     True
B     True
C    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 6):

Probably the best way is to obtain a dataframe column as a numpy array without copying data around (using [the `.values` property](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#attributes-and-the-raw-ndarray-s) after column selection via indexing), and to then use a numpy-based test for checking monotonicity:

```
def monotonic(x):
    return np.all(np.diff(x) > 0)

monotonic(df[0].values)
```

A pure Python implementation, borrowed from here: [Python - How to check list monotonicity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983258/python-how-to-check-list-monotonicity)

```
def strictly_increasing(L):
    return all(x<y for x, y in zip(L, L[1:]))
```

Comment: i like this Python-way because it can be applied to a combination of columns too, for instance, as i had to check that pairs (read_date, read_time) in my df are sorted properly, i could simply do: strictly_increasing(list(zip(df['read_date'], df['read_time'])))

Answer (score 2):

If two indices are equal, they won't be unique. So you can just use:

```
my_df.Index.is_monotonic and my_df.Index.is_unique
```

These attributes are documented in version 0.15.2; is_unique is mentioned sketchily in 0.14.1 but just worked for me. See

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/api.html#index

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.14.1/generated/pandas.Index.html

Answer (score 0):

you can just math this one:

```
diff = df[0] - df[0].shift(1)
is_monotonic = (diff < 0).sum() == 0 or (diff > 0).sum() == 0
```

all you're checking here is that either the differences are all >= 0 or all <= 0.

edit: since you only want strictly increasing, then it's just:

```
is_monotonic = (diff <= 0).sum() == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that by *strictly* increasing you mean that the values are integers and that neighbors are separated by exactly 1? As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131741/python-find-out-whether-a-list-of-integers-is-coherent), this is a simple method for checking named criterion:

```
def is_coherent(seq):
    return seq == range(seq[0], seq[-1]+1)
```

Using it with the first column of your `my_df` might look like so:

```
is_coherent(my_df[0].tolist())
```

Comment: Yes, increasing, but not specificaly by 1.

Comment: So, what means "strictly"?

Comment: strict monotonically increasing means x < x+1 while monotonically increasing means x <= x+1