# How to check each column in pandas data frame are in ascending order or not

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

i want to know each column in pandas data frame are in ascending order or not.

```
**col1** **col2**  **col3**

99   102   103

97   103   107

100   108   109
```

for col1, col2 and col3 how to find which columns are in ascending order and which columns are not.

Comment: I think your question has already been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28093365/is-a-column-in-pandas-df-monotonically-increasing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a column in pandas.DF() monotonically increasing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28093365/is-a-column-in-pandas-df-monotonically-increasing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.is_monotonic)
```

Answer (score 1):

`is_monotonic` is deprecated.  Now use:

```
assert df["x"].is_monotonic_increasing
assert df["y"].is_monotonic_increasing
assert df["z"].is_monotonic_increasing
```