# Is there an effective way to fit the following two datasets with lsqcurvefit?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, data-fitting, scientific-computing

I have two complex datasets for which I intend to find a suitable function to fit them. The first dataset is presented as follows:

[image]

As you can see, although complicated, it seems that this dataset is a combination of rectangle functions. These data describe the relation of 'Amplitude' of complex numbers with time. The second picture looks like this:

[image]

And this relation actually describes the 'Phase' of the above complex numbers with time, it seems that they are also combinations of rectangle functions. At first, I want to use combinations of Fourier cosine and sine series to fit the amplitude and phase using

```
lsqcurvefit
```

in MATLAB, but it seems that the provided parameters fail to converge to the correct values. (I have tried a number of options, like adjusting FiniteDifferenceStepSize, FiniteDifferenceType, StepTolerance and so on). Despite many failures, I saw someone said we could use Normal cumulative distribution function (CDF) to fit a step function, and I thought that it might be possible if we use the combinations of parameterized CDF and

```
y = erfc(x)
```

to achieve successful fitting. So, could anyone provide any solutions or ways to fit the above two relations? Giving some valuable ideas will also be very helpful to me.

PS: For now I don't care any hidden physics inside these data, and all I want to do is to find a mathematical way to fit the above two relations in MATLAB.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, it seems that interpolation works much better.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58286487/803359) may help, especially due to the fact that the jumps are very clear and easy to detect.