# Find the first element in a list where all subsequent values increment by one

Tags: python, list

I would like to find the value in a list, after which all other values increase by 1 only.

```
# Input
my_list1 = [2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
my_list2 = [6, 7, 9, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
my_list3 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
```

```
# Output
my_list1 = 15
my_list2 = 20
my_list3 = 18
```

I was thinking about looping backwards through the lists and when the decrease is larger than 1, extract the value at this position.

```
for x in reversed(my_list1):
    if x decrease > 1:
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an `itertools` based one, useful if we have a *very* long list, so we don't have load it into memory. Here [`dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) will drop values from the iterable while the condition holds, we only need to take the `next` element in the resulting iterable. Note that `next` has a default argument, which we can just set to `None` to avoid having the `StopIteration` error being raised:

```
from itertools import tee, dropwhile

def first_diff(it):
    i, j = tee(reversed(it), 2)
    next(j)
    return next((dropwhile(lambda e: e==(next(j)+1), i)), None)
```

---

```
first_diff(my_list1)
# 15
first_diff(my_list2)
# 20
first_diff(my_list3)
# 18
```

Comment: This is the only solution worth upvoting. BTW, since you are using `itertools` you might want  to avoid the while: `return next(dropwhile(lambda e: e==next(j)+1, i))`

Answer (score 2):

You could [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) lists into pairs, then use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to get the first pair where the difference is greater than 1. We can then unpack the first item from the result.

```py
def first_diff_pair(lst):
    return next(
        (fst for fst, snd in zip(reversed(lst), reversed(lst[:-1])) if fst - snd > 1),
        None,
    )
```

To avoid `next()` returning `StopIteration` when no result is found and the iterator is exhausted, we can set the default value to `None`.

**Output:**

```py
>>> first_diff_pair([2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24])
15
>>> first_diff_pair([6, 7, 9, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28])
20
>>> first_diff_pair([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25])
18
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities with list comprehensions. Here I collect every number that increased by more then one, store them in a list and show the last one:

```
print([my_list1[i+1] for i in range(len(my_list1)-1) if my_list1[i+1] - my_list1[i] > 1][-1])
print([my_list2[i+1] for i in range(len(my_list2)-1) if my_list2[i+1] - my_list2[i] > 1][-1])
print([my_list3[i+1] for i in range(len(my_list3)-1) if my_list3[i+1] - my_list3[i] > 1][-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I tried this, and it worked, but there maybe better and more efficient solutions to it too,

```py
l = len(my_list1) - 1
for x in reversed(my_list1):
    if my_list1[l] - my_list1[l - 1] == 1:
      l -= 1
      continue
    else:
      print(x)
      break
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic loop-based implementation.

```
def get_first_diff(my_list):
    reversed_iter = reversed(my_list)
    last = next(reversed_iter)
    for v in reversed_iter:
        if last - v != 1:
           return last
        last = v
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution with no duplicate code:

```
my_list1 = [2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
my_list2 = [6, 7, 9, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
my_list3 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]

def getIncreaseStartPoint(nums):
  i = len(nums) - 1
  while (nums[i] - nums[i - 1] == 1):
    i -= 1
    if (i == 0):
      return nums[0]
  return nums[i]

print("mylist_1 =", getIncreaseStartPoint(my_list1))
print("mylist_2 =", getIncreaseStartPoint(my_list2))
print("mylist_3 =", getIncreaseStartPoint(my_list3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt:

```
my_list1 = [2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]

tmplist = [x - i for i, x in enumerate(my_list1)]
first = my_list1[tmplist.index(tmplist[-1])]
# result 15
```

How it works:

```
# tmplist is [2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

Repeating numbers show places of increasing sequences (by +1) in the original list. Last item (`tmplist[-1]`) is 6, we want to get the position of the first such item (`tmplist.index(...)`), because there the sequence starts. Finally we look up the value at that index (`my_list1[...]`)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the [Splitting list based on missing numbers in a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3149440/7851470), you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group consecutive runs of numbers, and from there to get the first value of the last run:

```
from itertools import groupby

my_list = [2, 5, 7,8,9,10,11,12,13, 15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
first_value = None
for _, group in groupby(enumerate(my_list), lambda x: x[1] - x[0]):
    first_value = next(group)[1]
print(first_value)
# 15
```